# Reverse relationships in Prismic

Tags: rest, graphql, prismic.io

Suppose I have a simple blog with the data type of `Article` and the data type of `ArticleTag`:

```
Article ->
    title - Title field
    tag - Content relationship to ArticleTag

ArticleTag ->
    title - Title field
    icon - Text field
```

For that purpose, I would like to return query all ArticleTags and get each with N Articles (or even all of them), but the API documentation (both [GraphQL](https://prismic.io/docs/graphql/query-the-api/fetch-linked-document-fields) and [REST](https://prismic.io/docs/rest-api/query-the-api/fetch-linked-document-fields)) is awfully silent on how to expand reverse content relationships. i.e. they only specify how to get fields from `ArticleTag` per `Article` (or how to get all `Articles` with a specific `ArticleTag` *per id* which is strange but whatever)

I can think of a workaround: query all tags, then for each tag query all articles. Thing is that this sounds awfully slow as it generates N+1 API requests for the number of tags I have, plus, this may be happening on the client-side as well in this project! So I'd rather avoid that if in any way possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the workaround you presented is the only way to do that.